# Alignment - text beside images

Tags: graphics, text, alignment

I am struggling due to having text beside a figure. I am trying to have a images at top right corner and aligning text beside of the left side of the figure.

```
\textsc{\large Technical University of Denmark}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2,right]{Images/DTU}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You probably don't want the `figure` environment here (it causes its contents to float, that is its very purpose). You should provide a drawing or so to clarify, but your needs can probably be fulfilled with the `tabbing` environment or a `minipage` containing a first line or paragraph with `\includegraphics`, then the text you want to have beneath (unless I misunderstood your “beside”). Also, please provide a minimal working example using `\includegraphics{example-image}` for instance (everyone has this image) and concrete sample text, that compiles as is with no error.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking this is what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.png}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: As I understand the question, image is on the right and text on the left :-)

Comment: Thank you @Zarko